# how to set a notepad made with Qt as the default text editor in windows

Tags: c++, qt5

i made a notepad with qt creator following the example from qt website documentation.
it works fine, i deployed it ,made an installer.
but i can't make it as default program for text files.
i want to open a text file with it without launching the app and clicking open and choosing the file location.
is there a code to add.
i didn't know exactly what to search for.     (i'm new to coding)

link to the example:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tutorials-notepad-notepad-cpp.html

Comment: that does not depend on Qt but on the configuration of your OS

Comment: when i click open with on a text file and choose my app, it don't show on the list of available programs. can you help me solve this.

Comment: You do not recognize it because your application is not registered in windows, for more information read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46218044/make-a-qt-c-program-show-its-file-types-as-known-on-windows

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i've used another installer maker that have a file associations parameter, with that my app been added to default programs.
and i modified the code to get the file path from command line parameters argv[1].

and it worked.